# Compute end time of an activity

Tags: stata

I have the beginning time of a surgery (`new_time`) in %tc format and I also have the length of the surgery (`th_time`) in minutes (e.g. 140 mins) and unformatted.

I would like to know how to proceed to add `th_time` to `new_time` in order to get the end time of the surgery.

Here's how I formatted so far my variables:

```
gen time_temp = substr(intotheatre, strpos(intotheatre," ")+1, . )
gen new_time = clock(intotheatre, "DMY hms",2050)
format new_time %tc 

generate hrs=hh(new_time)
generate mins=mm(new_time)
generate secs=ss(new_time)

drop if th_time < 0 | th_time == .
drop if theatre==""

sort theatre new_time
```

I have read Stata Journals from Nick Cox but every attempt I made trying to generate the end_time ended up with '`type mismatch`' from Stata.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not already done so, it would benefit you to work your way through the guidance in `help datetime`, which is without a doubt the most visited documentation on my system, with the second-most-visited being Chapter 24 (Working with dates and times) of the *Stata User's Guide* PDF available from the PDF Documentation item on Stata's Help menu. Before working with dates and times, any Stata user should read the very detailed Chapter 24 thoroughly. After that, the help documentation will usually be enough to point the way. Some people may be able to remember everything without have to continually refer to the documentation, but I for one am not such a person.

With that said, your `new_time` variable should be created as a double

```
generate double new_time = clock(intotheatre, "DMY hms",2050)
```

as both the cited documentation and Nick Cox advise. You have `new_time` represented now as the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1960. Then converting the theatre time from minutes to milliseconds and adding

```
generate double end_time = new_time + ( th_time * 60 * 1000 )
format end_time %tc
```

should give you what you desire.

Comment: Thanks, this is more straightforward than I thought it would be - I believed I had to modify the format of `th_time` before any computation

Comment: Glad to help, thank you for closing the loop. The most important lesson in the recommended reading is that the display format of any sort of Stata number - specifically dates and times, but true generally - has no effect at all on computations done with that number.